# Pasted text is reduced in size when copied from ask question description/body

Tags: bug, ios-app, paste

### Steps to Reproduce ##

1. Tap ask a question
2. type some text in body/description field
3. copy/cut
4. Paste in different location
5. Notice text size is smaller

### Expectation

Given I have copied text, when I paste the text in the same or a different location, then the text size will be the same as when I copied it.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 7
- OS Version: Version 13.1.3 (Build 17A878)

Comment: @Glorfindel I think that's a different bug. There the text would retain displayed formatting from the source only in the editing view, but if that were the problem here, it should have the same formatting since it was copied from and pasted to the same input field.

Comment: It's essentially the same bug (I've edited that question to remove the part about comments, which made it a partial duplicate). @YvetteColomb this is the default and only editor for the iOS app, in my opinion it's valid bug report (but a duplicate).

Comment: @Glorfindel why did you retract your close vote here then?

Comment: Because I was confident I'd find another duplicate. But I didn't :)